# jQuery .pdf function not running in Joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, joomla

I've got easy folder listing installed that is outputting menu's for a website i'm working on. 
I would like to have a jQuery function that opens each .pdf in a new window, except it's not working at the moment.

Here's my jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $('a[href$=".pdf"]').attr('target', '_blank');
}); 
</script>
```

Website url : http://www.thewatermansarms.net

Can you help as to why it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include a link to the jQuery lib *before* that block of code.